# What is the difference between the term "UI that gets rendered on client side" and "..on server side "?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between the term "UI that gets rendered on client side" and "..on server side "?

Any examples of technologies ?

- UI Client Side = ?
- UI Server Side = ?

not only web development sucks I guess that nothing ever gets rendered on the server side ?

Comment: hmmm... the UI always gets rendered by the browser/application on the client side... I guess it depends on how "wide" we want to stretch the term "render".  The one exception I could think of: terminal servers (the UI bits are transported to the client side but are rendered on the server side).

Comment: are you assuming a Web environment?

Comment: Not for a meaningful value of 'render'. HTML interface: rendered on server. Silverlight: rendered in client. Ajax: don't ask.

Comment: @Joe: HTML code is **produced** on the server side, the Client side interprets & renders (output to graphics) the HTML. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)

Comment: @jldupont - I think you're missing the point of what the OP is asking. Forget the produced vs. rendered semantic argument - I'm fairly sure the OP wants to understand the difference between html that is generated on the server vs. html DOM manipulation on the client. I'm quite used to that being referred to as "rendered on the server" vs "rendered on the client".

Comment: Typically, the server renders templates into html, the client renders html into a dom tree and renders that dom tree into graphics.

Comment: abmv, maybe instead of being hostile and continously repeating a phrase that only has meaning to you, you could provide some examples of where you've seen the phrase "server side UI"? was it on this site?

Comment: @Rob L: I admire your attempt to be diplomatic, but you can see by the OP's initial attitude and refusal to clarify that he's more frustrated than curious or confused.

Comment: I never seen server side UI in my life so just wanted to update my self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that for a client/server to be classed as 'rendering' something it must involve some form of calculation based on some input to produce output that is intended for viewing or printing.  Beyond that we then have to look at how much work is being done, relatively speaking, in order to produce the output.

So, I would not class a server that pumps out pixel data via a network connection as having rendered anything unless it's done some work to get those pixels.  E.g. a Web Server piping back a bitmap hasn't rendered anything.  But a terminal server that is streaming back a live computer desktop has.

It's best to think of Application Examples and try to describe those in terms of client/server.

- A Desktop App that reads a database and displays its data is rendering client-side.
- A Desktop App that employs some form of parameterised XML template-based UI that is stored in a database and retrieved (and formatted) by a stored procedure could be argued to be client and server.
- A Direct3d game that downloads vertex data from a server is client-side
- However, if the vertex data is dynamic, and the server has to do some calculations to serve it up, then you could also argue client + server rendering is taking place.
- Web pages are nearly always a mix of client + server, especially those based on Asp.Net, JSP or PHP for example; since the page output is dynamic and therefore the HTML has to be 'rendered' by the server before then being rendered by the client.

It's difficult to provide concrete answers for any sole technology.

Windows Forms, Direct3D, OpenGL, iPhone et al, Flash, Pure WPF, Silverlight and all the rest are all capable of being pure client-side UI, and a mix - depending on the application.

I suppose you could argue, however, that there is no such thing as a pure server-side UI (can't wait for a comment from someone who can point to one!)

Comment: Watermarking images. Shouldn't be considered as server-side rendering?

Comment: Absolutely - if that watermark is being dynamically applied to a non-watermarked image.

Answer (score 4):

I assume a web envorinment.

**Client side**

A page that uses javascript to create the final DOM, its client side rendering. GWT by example. AJAX in general.

If you use Flash you also use client-side rendering. The plugin is the one drawing all.

They both load some kind of logic at the client, retrieve data from server and then decide what concrete data to display (each name, number, date, etc) in the page. The code loaded into the client (the javascript, the flash) doesn't change from use to use.

**Server side**

Server side will be a JSP page (or any technology) to create a final HTML. Anyway the browser is the one who renders, but the decision "there are 5 clients so there are five rows one with each LastName" is taken at server side, not client side.

Comment: Of course, all kind of RIA (rich internet apps) using more than HTML+CSS+Javascript should fall into the client side rendering category...

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a web environment, then:

**Server Side** refers to any html that is generated on the server (e.g. within ASP.NET) and sent to the web browser. This is probably most of the web page.

**Client side** refers to anything that runs in the browser and changes the page's html from there. Generally, this means Javascript (with one or more Javascript library such as jQuery) manipulating the web page document (DOM) once it is already in the web browser.

As an example, in the world of "Ajax", this often means that the *server* renders the initial web page, but that javascript on the *client* then amends the web page in response to user input (probably having actually communicated with the server behind the scenes), without having to actually post the whole page back to the server to have it re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that rendering in this meaning = process of creation some 'what should I display' data, not the actual conversion of 'what should I display' to raster image shown on display.

- UI Client Side = windows forms, XPF, Delphi, Qt, GTK, ....
- Server Side = HTML+CSS

Comment: How does the server actually "render" HTML/CSS?

Comment: The interface state gets rendered into HTML on the server. The HTML gets rendered into pixels on the client. 'Render' can be used at a number of different abstractions.

Comment: @Anton - HTML is rendered on the server by, for example, binding values to XML.

Comment: If we agree that the definition of "render" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics) ) then the rendering process only occurs on the Client side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't take wikipedia as a reliable source of definiton. Even if I did, the rendering should occur on server side too -> adding watermark to picture isn't rendering?